# Importing multiple .csv file into R by names of file

Tags: r, csv

I have a folder that contains 332 .csv files, from 001.csv to 332.csv. They have the same header.
If I want to calculate the mean of an object from the files (its names is from a.csv to b.csv). How can I merge data in file a,a+1,a+2,...b into a dataframe?
Example: Input 5:130;
Process: reading data from files 005.csv, 006.csv, 007.csv, ..., 130.csv then merging them in a dataframe.

Comment: I think the question has been answered before

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r

Comment: What do you mean by dataframe? Would it be sufficient (and possible) to simply read x csv-files and and use cbind() to join them? If so, you could write a simple loop.

Comment: You could import each file into a third dimension of an `array` and go from there.

Comment: In my opinion there is no complete answer on the other question which answers this question. I think it is therefore not correct to mark this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Supposing you have all the `.csv` files in one folder, the following function will give you what you need:

```
# defining the function
merged <- function(id = 1:332) {
  df <- data.frame()
  for(i in 1:length(id)){
    add <- read.csv(as.character(paste0(sprintf("%03s",id[i]),".csv")))
    df <- rbind(df,add)
  }
  colnames(df) <- c(..specify the colnames in here..)
  assign("dat", df, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

# getting your merged df
merged(5:130)
```

The merged dataframes are now in the dataframe `dat`

Comment: Something goes wrong. Actually, paste0(sprintf("%03s",id[i]),".csv") just returns "  id[i].csv". For example, paste0(sprintf("%03s",1),".csv") returns "  1.csv"

Comment: That's strange. I tested this on probably the same set of `csv` files (from the Coursera course "Computing for Data Analysis" / "R programming") and it works perfectly. For this function to work, you have to set the working directory to the directory were all the `csv` files are located. After that you can use the function.