# Reading multiple csv files from a folder into a single dataframe in R

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a folder containing 332 csv files. The name of the files are as follows 001.csv, 002.csv, 003.csv, ............ , 330.csv, 331.csv , 332.csv . All the files have same number of variables and same format.

I need to read all the files in one dataframe. I have been reading each one and then using rbind, but this is too cumbersome.

Need help.

Comment: Although the duplicate will give you a good idea from what to do, this exact problem has been posted before in other questions [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951541/importing-multiple-csv-file-into-r-by-names-of-file/23952165#23952165).

Comment: I too, have 332 csv files in my Coursera assigment ;)

Answer (score 50):

Try lapply and do.call

```
file_names <- dir() #where you have your files

your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv))
```

Comment: This is helpful. Just to add a reminder: include "full.names = TRUE" in dire() if only folder names were read.

Answer (score 18):

Solution with `data.table`, answer is taken from another post in SO which I used sometimes back.

```
library(data.table)  
files <- list.files(path = "/etc/dump",pattern = ".csv")
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
data <- rbindlist( temp )
```

Comment: How to capture the name of the files as well in the data frame in a separate column to identify the source of the data?

Comment: @Arun I think you might need to add 2x backslashes before the `.csv` in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. Could probably also be done with a apply function.

```
path <- "path_to_files"
files <- c(paste("00",2:9,".csv",sep=""),
           paste("0",10:99,".csv",sep=""), 
           paste(100:332,".csv",sep="")
           )
#Read first file to create variables in a data frame
data <- read.csv(paste(path,"001.csv",sep="/"))

#Read remaining files and rbind them to dataset
for (f in files) {
   data <- rbind(data,read.csv(paste(path, files, sep="/")))
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your immediate help. The following commands with header=TRUE worked for me.                                                                                                                         file_names <- dir() #where you have your files

your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv, header=TRUE))