# For-Loop read and save multiple .xlsx files to one file

Tags: r, rbind

I am looping through multiple files where each file creates a table. I would like to save each table to a file so that I have all of the tables together. The idea is that after each file runs, the final output will append to the previous final output in a table. My current code loops through each file but only takes the data from the last file in the folder and repeatedly appends to the same output. Here is my code:

```
filenames <- Sys.glob("*.xlsx")
print(filenames)

final.df<-data.table()
for(i in 1:length(filenames)) {
   #... final table named "Stats"

   Stats$file <- i   #To view which file is listed
   df <- data.table(Stats)
   final.df <- rbind(final.df, df)
   drop(df)
}
```

When I run the code, the file names are printed 26 times in this format:

```
[1] "file1.xlsx"          "file2.xlsx"
[1] "file1.xlsx"          "file2.xlsx"
[1] "file1.xlsx"          "file2.xlsx"
...
```

My current output prints in this format:

```
X        Y        Z       File
1        10       2       file2
2        6        2       file2
1        9        2       file2
1        10       2       file2
2        6        2       file2
1        9        2       file2
```

My desired output would look like the following:

```
X        Y        Z       File
0        4        1       file1
1        7        1       file1
0        1        1       file1
1        10       2       file2
2        6        2       file2
1        9        2       file2
```

**SOLUTION**

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx$")
print(files)

final.df<-list() 

for(title in c(paste(files, sep="."))) {
   #... (Some data named Stats)
   Stats<-data.table(Stats)
   final.df[[title]] <- Stats
   print(final.df)
 }
 Final <- rbindlist(final.df)
```

Comment: This is probably answered and is duplicated. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819433/reading-multiple-csv-files-from-a-folder-into-a-single-dataframe-in-r

Comment: Some more inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32888757/2204410

Comment: I know how to read each individual file, I am looking to append the output I get after reading the file. I believe these solutions append the original files together, which is not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your data, I think this should work:

```
listOut <- list()
for(i in 1:length(filenames)) {
  df <- data.table(filenames[i])
  listOut[[i]] <- df
}

dfFinal <- rbindlist(listOut)
```

The idea is to make a dataframe and append it to a list for each of your files.  Then you can rbind all of the list elements together.  This is much more efficient than trying to append to an existing dataframe.

Comment: This answer makes sense, but my output is still taking the last file in my folder and appending a duplicate result.

Comment: Yeah, I'm having a hard time imagining this without seeing the data.  I made an edit above.  If that doesn't work, can you share the files somewhere?

Comment: I had to do something a little different with the loop line, but otherwise this was a great solution.