# Reading multiple csv files into a single df AND adding a number iterator as a column to the df

Tags: r

I'm reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819433/reading-multiple-csv-files-from-a-folder-into-a-single-dataframe-in-r) SO post.

The top voted answer for reading multiple csv files into a single dataframe is:

```
file_names <- dir() #where you have your files
your_data_frame <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv))
```

My question is, suppose I have 5 files and I'd like to add a column on the new dataframe indicating which order the file was read in, 1 through 5. How can I do that? Do I have to doa. for loop using an iterator i or is there a neat way to encompass with the short code block above?

Comment: Use `data.table::rbindlist` with it's argument `idcol = TRUE`.

Comment: I would suggest using `rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), idcol = TRUE)` command from the linked post (uses `fread` from the `data.table` package)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll use data.table as backup but would prefer tidyverse or base r if there's a solution out there?