# Merging Dataframes containing Strings with Different Row in R langguage

Tags: r

Currently having problem binding two sets of dataframes together.

```
Folder1 <-list.files(path[1],pattern=".csv")

Folder2 <-list.files(path[2],pattern=".csv")

File <-rbind(Folder1,Folder2)
```

> Error:SQL logic error missing database near "AS":syntax error

Comment: Firstly, you need to know what's the data class of `Folder1`. Obviously, it's not data frame. `list.files` only list the file name. It can't output the data frame. You need to read them with something like `fread` or `read.csv`.

Comment: I have set Folder1<-data.frame(), then will Folder1<- list.files(path[1]) be a dataframe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819433/reading-multiple-csv-files-from-a-folder-into-a-single-dataframe-in-r

Comment: What is `path` ? What is `length(path)` ? Are you trying to combine all the files in `path` together as one dataframe?

Comment: I am trying to combine all files name in certain folders into one big data frame such that I will have a big list of names of files. Only the name of the files and not the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You are not understanding exactly what `list.files` does. It creates a list of all the file**names** that match your pattern and/or path. That does not mean however that anything has been imported yet.

This is the construction I usually use:

```
library(data.table) #for fread and rbindlist

Folder1_reads <- list()
Folder1_list <- list.files(path[1],pattern=".csv")
for (i in 1:length(Folder1_list)) {
  Folder1_reads[[i]] <- fread(paste(path[1], Folder1_list[i], sep = "/")) #maybe you won't need the "/" depending on what is in path[1]
}
Folder1 <- rbindlist(Folder1_reads)
```